# How to add Vector2 position to list of game object that was previously in panel (not in Canvas)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a list of Vector2 positions. X positions goes from -190 to 190 and Y from -300 to 325. When object is instantiated to a panel as parent at a position i remove it from list and when object is destroyed i add position of object back to list, but there is a problem.
When i try to get the position of game object i get position where both X and Y position are close to 0 or 1 like (-1.025,0.3). At the and all my object are instantiated close (if not on top) to each other.
What should i do?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you give a GameObject a parent transform, its `transform.localPosition` will return coordinates relative to its parent's transform's position.  As such, a `transform.localPosition` of (-1.025,0.3) means that it is 1.025 units left of its parent and 0.3 units upwards of it.

If you use `transform.position` instead, you will get the absolute position in world space.  This should have the expected values for x and y.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you likely are instantiating incorrectly.  Make sure you use the `Instantiate` method with `instantiateInWorldSpace` set to `true`, like so:

```cs
Instantiate(myObject, myParent, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not what i was looking for. What i was asking is why i set the position x: -190 to 190 etc, but when i want to get the position afterwards i get like (-1.025,0.3).